# ajax - See if 2 URLs exist

Tags: javascript, ajax

what I have at the minute works for the first URL test, however, I don't know how to get it to test the second URL, should the first one not exist.

```
    var str = document.title.replace(/ | My Site/i, '');
    var title = str.replace(/ /g, '-');
    var finish = title.toLowerCase();
    var banner = finish.split('-', 1)[0]
    var address = "http://example.com/images/" + finish + ".jpg";
    var banneraddress = "http://example.com/images/" + banner + "-banner.jpg";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'HEAD',
        url: address,
            success: function() {
                // Primary URL exists
                document.getElementById("TRY").src = address;
            },
            error: function() {
                $.ajax({
                type: 'HEAD',
                url: banneraddress,
                    success: function() {
                        // Secondary URL exists
                        document.getElementById("TRY").src = banneraddress;
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        // Both failed
                        null
                    }
                });
            }
    });
```

What needs to happen is if the user loads a page and /images/page-title.jpg exists, it will add that src to the the images with the ID "TRY".

If that test fails, if /images/page-banner.jpg exists add that src to the images

And, for now, if neither work do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your AJAX logic to separate function, later you can ask the function  if both images exists, and if they, you can change the `src` attribute of your image.

E.g.

```
if( checkIfImageExists(address) && checkIfImageExists(banner_address) ) {
    // both images exists, change src attribute
} else {
    // both images do not exists, do something else
}
```

You should modify your `success` and `error` callbacks to return `true` or `false`.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly: if( checkIfImageExists("example.com/images/" + finish + ".jpg") || checkIfImageExists("example.com/images/" + banner + "-banner.jpg") ){ if(1 exists){show image 1}else{show image 2}? (essentially)?

Comment: Yes, but you can use variables directly - `address` and `banner_address`.